# cakephpとcakeそれぞれの利点と欠点を教えて下さい

Tags: php, cakephp

今までcakephpを使ってきたのですが、ウェブアプリでcakeを採用するべきか悩んでいます。
[海外動向](http://qiita.com/shukotang/items/055058b33b553b48c164)にあわせたいのですが、日本ではcakephpが主流になっている様に感じられました。

phpフレームワークを利用したことがある方で、それぞれの利点と欠点がわかる方がいらっしゃったら教えて下さい。

Comment: 回答に求める幅が漠然かつ主観的ですので、例えば今cakeを使っていてどういう悩みを感じているのか具体的に書かれると良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cakephpを複数のプロジェクトで採用したことがあります。今関わっているプロジェクトではLaravel4.2を採用しました。

フレームワークはメリット・デメリットが色々あるので、比較すべき項目に重みをつけて採用基準を作り、しっかり比較検討するのが大事かなと思います。チームによって重要視する項目が違うので、何を採用すべきなのかはチームの方針次第かなと。

個人的にはCakeとLaravelだとどっちも同じくらいな印象ですが、Cakeは経験者がそこそこ集まりやすいのと、Laravelよりは情報収集が簡単なので、スピード優先の開発だとCakeを採用する事が多いです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました！

日本だとやはりララベルの開発者が少ないため、cakeの方が開発のスピードは速そうですね！参考になりました！